# Do animals get sick with hemorrhoids?

Tags: medicine, animal-husbandry, celiac-disease

Do animals get sick with hemorrhoids ?

And why Humans are most affected of it ?

Is it because the gravity center of Humans is sittuated in the anal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why are haemorrhoids more common in humans than in animals?

This is due to the majority of animals, including apes, are on all fours. Only the human species stands and walks straight up with two feet. Therefore, the blood in the body has enhanced arduousness in circulating and travelling back to the heart. A justification for the commonness of hemorrhoids in humans, is there is a higher frequency of blood congestion which then further leads to hemorrhoids.

### There are animals which can get haemorrhoids

1. Cats
2. Dogs
3. Apes
4. Horses

The reasons and causes why animals can also get hemorrhoids is similar to humans, besides the structural reasons. This may include:

In *Horses*

- The horse may strain while delivering young ones

> When the bowel movements are disturbed, as in constipation, it leads to an increase in pressure applied to the rectum region. Unlike humans, the increased pressure from constipation does not come from straining to get the excrements out, but from the impaction of the excrements within the horse and the resultant pressure that causes.  This in turn leads to expansion of the blood vessels around the anus and this may cause hemorrhoids and eventually bleeding.

In *cats*

> One of the main reasons behind the occurrence of cat hemorrhoids is heredity, which plays a major role in deciding who would and who would not get afflicted with this condition.
>
> Diets low in fiber and liquid content are the main cause of constipation, which in turn leads to excess pressure being applied during defecation and straining when bowels are passed. Too much pressure in the rectum and lower abdomen causes blood vessels in this region to expand, thus leading to the creation of lumps called hemorrhoids.

There have also been some [investigations](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16981041) in which haemorrhoids were induced by ligation of the inferior haemorrhoidal vein into apes. The outcome of this was that after a certain amount of days, there were hemorrhoidal piles in the anus in fifty percent of the animals. The outcome was unremarkable. There was no bleeding and all animals showed no signs of pain or suffering.

References:

- "Horse Haemorrhoids, Horse Hemorrhoids, Horse Haemorrhoids, Horse Piles - Web. 01 Mar. 2016.
- "Result Filters." National Center for Biotechnology Information. U.S. National Library of Medicine, Sept.-Oct. 2006. Web. 01 Mar. 2016.